# Battery Amp-Hours and C-rating (need clarification on formulas)

Tags: batteries, amperage

These formulas here are confusing me. I am not sure, exactly what some of the variables mean.

1. What is the **"Max. Amps"** exactly, in this formula?
2. What is the **"discharge.C.value"**?
3. What is the **"Discharge.Current"** exactly?
4. There is something i don’t understand about the discharge current formula. Why, in the formula when increase the discharge current, the discharge c value increases? Shouldn’t if i have a battery with 1Ah and i am pulling only 0.5A, the Discharge C should be 2hrs Instead of 0.5hrs? Since i am pulling less, not more?

[image: Formulas]

Comment: From the datasheets....get the values. C rates is just Max Amp/Capacity [Ah] normalized for. Slow use 20 h then depending on quality and Peukert’s curve capacity drops when used up<<1h rapidly

Comment: C rating is NOT  the maximum current. It's the max current scaled by the capacity. So a battery drained at 1C will be empty in an hour regardless of its capacity.  At C/2, it will be empty in 2 hours, and so on. And capacity may be reduced at high C ratings. A 
 lead acid battery may be measured at C/20 (20 hour rate), the capacity at C/2 or C will be little more than half that.

Comment: For current, there are two critical things you need to know about your usage: the peak current you'll ever need and the average current. If you select a battery that has a "maximum amp" specification that is higher than the peak current, you should be fine. Use the average amp requirement to help work out how long a battery will supply power. The C rating, assuming the amp-hours are the same in two different batteries, provides you with a way of judging how quickly you can discharge the battery. Higher discharge rate batteries (bigger C values) are more capable of peak current requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These look like equations I gave you in a previous answer.

> "*battery with 1Ah and i am pulling only 0.5A, the Discharge C should be 2hrs instead of 0.5hrs*"

The discharge C is 0.5 (3rd eqn). So it will empty in 1/0.5 = 2 hours (2nd eqn).

C numbers are a current **normalized** to battery capacity. They are not current. They are not amps. What they are is a multiple of a particular current relative to the amp-hours if you chopped off the "hours" part. Basically a multiple of how much current the battery can supply for 1 hour before dying.

C-numbers tell you how hard you are running a battery *for its size*. So a really big battery with a very low maximum C-rating might still be able to output more current than a tiny battery with a very high max C-rating. But the big battery will be very weak (low power) for it size while the small battery will be very powerful for it size.

The energy doesn't change so at maximum current, the large battery will last a very long time since it is huge but you can't draw current from it very quickly. Conversely the tiny battery could be emptied very quickly since you can draw very high current from it but it doesn't have a lot of capacity to begin with.

---

Imagine two gas tanks. 1000L and 250L. The opening on both is sized so if you turn it upside down and let everything pour out as fast as possible, it takes 1 hour to empty. That is a max C-rating of 1 because both drain in 1 hour at maximum speed, but the large tank can empty at 1000L/h while the small tank empties at 250L/h. That is like current.

Now make the small tank have a bigger opening so it drains in 0.25 hours. That is a maximum C-rating of 4. So this 250L tank can empty at 1000L/h. Even though it is smaller, it can produce a flow equal to the 1000L tank. Of course, since it contains less gas, if you use this rate it will not last nearly as long as the 1000L tank.

If you take the 1000L tank and reduce the opening so it takes 10 hours to empty when turned upside down, this is a max C-rating of 0.1 and a max current 100L/hour. Even less flow than the small tanks, but you store a lot of gas so it will take a long time to empty, but cannot supply something that needs burns gas very quickly.

I hope that helps you visualize things.

Comment: C is not dimensionless: [C] = [Amps]/([Amps]*[Hour]) = 1/[Hour]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_battery#C_rate

Comment: @Konstantin That's true. I hestiateto give those particular units though since they are not intuitive to how to use the value.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the "discharge.C.value"?

Per your formula, it is the discharge current divided by the current capacity in amp hours such that a battery discharged at 1 C discharges in 1 hour, a battery discharged at 2C discharges in 1/2 hour, etc.

The idea is to normalize the rate of charge or discharge to the size of the battery.  The reason for this is that as you increase battery capacity by adding more cells, your max discharge and charge rates go up since the current is divided across more cells.

> What is the "Discharge.Current" exactly?

The number of amps you are drawing from the battery.  Similarly the charge current is the number of amps you are charging the battery at.

> Shouldn’t if i have a battery with 1Ah and i am pulling only 0.5A, the Discharge C should be 2hrs Instead of 0.5hrs?

Discharge is in units of inverse hour, not hours, so as you increase the discharge rate the number of amps being discharged goes up.  The number of hours of battery life goes down.